# IE CSS Overlay Help

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, text, overlay

The code below works like a charm in Firefox and Safari but I can't get it to work in IE at all. In IE there is no overlay at all. Can anyone help me get it in IE.

http://pastebin.com/Kv4MbYyc
<strike>I put it on pastebin because the code tag formatting would not work for me.</strike>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image"> <img src="Picture.jpg"/> 
    <itext><span>Text at top</span></itext> 

    <stext><span>Text at bottom</span></stext> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 

}

itext span {
    position: absolute;
    Top: 20;
    left: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
    font: bold 45px/75px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
}

stext span {
    position: absolute;
    Bottom: 0;
    left: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
    font: 20px/30px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: Left;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4CqZ/11/ What version of IE?

Comment: Why are you using tags named `itext` and `stext`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `<div class="itext">` instead of `<itext>`, and `<div class="stext">` instead of `<stext>`.

Additionally, adding `display: inline` will obviate your need to use `<span>` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help D.N.. That took care of it. And, you were right about the display: inline as well.

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to upvote any answers you liked (in this case, I'd upvote both since they were both helpful) and accept the answer that best solved your issue.  No, it's not required, but it's the "nice" thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support HTML5 with custom tags, IE doesn't support them. You can use an alternative and use `div` probably with `id`. Here example code:

**html**

```
<div class="image"> <img src="Picture.jpg"/>
    <div id="itext"><span>Text at top</span></div>

    <div id="stext"><span>
        Text at bottom
        </span></div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}

#itext span {
    position: absolute;
    Top: 20;
    left: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
    font: bold 45px/75px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
}

#stext span {
    position: absolute;
    Bottom: 0;
    left: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
    font: 20px/30px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: Left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q4CqZ/12/

Of course you will see that the background in IE will be black, to achieve the opacity for internet explorer you can use

```
opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
```

More: http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2006/08/16/css-opacity-in-internet-explorer-ie/

Comment: Replacing the background: rbg statements with opacity:, filter: and background-color: statements was also very helpful thank you!